# Sentence-level to document-level sentiment analysis. Analysing news

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I need to perform sentiment analysis on news articles about a specific topic using the Stanford NLP tool.

Such tool only allows sentence based sentiment analysis while I would like to extract a sentiment evaluation of the whole articles with respect to my topic.

For instance, if my topic is Apple, I would like to know the sentiment of a news article with respect to Apple.

Just computing the average of the sentences in my articles won't do. For instance, I might have an article saying something along the lines of "Apple is very good at this, and this and that. While Google products are very bad for these reasons". Such an article would result in a Neutral classification using the average score of sentences, while it is actually a Very positive article about Apple.

On the other hand filtering my sentences to include only the ones containing the word Apple would miss articles along the lines of "Apple's product A is pretty good. However, it lacks the following crucial features: ...". In this case the effect of the second sentence would be lost if I were to use only the sentences containing the word Apple.

Is there a standard way of addressing this kind of problems? Is Stanford NLP the wrong tool to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: You might want to look into 
http://blog.getprismatic.com/deeper-content-analysis-with-aspects/

This is a very active area of research so it would be hard to find an off-the-shelf tool to do this (at least nothing is built in the Stanford CoreNLP). Some pointers: look into aspect-based sentiment analysis. In this case, Apple would be an "aspect" (not really but can be modeled that way). Andrew McCallum's group at UMass, Bing Liu's group at UIC, Cornell's NLP group, among others, have worked on this problem.

If you want a quick fix, I would suggest to extract sentiment from sentences that have reference to Apple and its products; use coref (check out dcoref annotator in Stanford CoreNLP), which will increase the recall of sentences and solve the problem of sentences like "However, it lacks..".

Comment: the link to the blog is not loading for me